# LESS CSS compilers returning blank

Tags: install-from-source, css, nodejs

I am not even sure where to start debugging this.  Months ago, I could happily compile my CSS from my LESS files.  Today, I run either `recess --compile test.less` or `lessc test.less` and I just get a blank output.  No errors. `lessc test.less > test.css` just creates a blank file.  The twitter-bootstrap Makefile for LESS errors, all be it not helpfully.

I'm using the following simple `test.less` to debug:

```
@color: #4D926F;
#header {
  color: @color;
}
h2 {
   color: @color;
}
```

I'm on ubuntu 12.10, I used `sudo apt-get install node-less` to provide `lessc`, and installed [recess from the directions on github](https://github.com/twitter/recess) (npm).  Both just give me empty output.

Even `lessc --version` returns nothing.

```
 which lessc
```

shows

```
/usr/local/bin/lessc
```

and the file isn't empty.

Something must have happened to my `node` installation perhaps, but no idea how to debug this.  `apt-get remove --purge node-less` and reinstalling didn't help.

Many thanks for the help or any tips on debugging!

Comment: Yeah, `/usr/local/bin/lessc` is not the correct location when it's from the official repo: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/all/node-less/filelist ... I guess you installed it in the system path using `sudo npm ...` which is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Ubuntu and other distributions, you should prefer the distribution packages instead of manually installing packages. So, first of all, you should remove the **recess** installed via **npm**:

```
sudo npm uninstall recess -g
```

Also remove the **node-less** package installed via `apt-get`, so that we can start with a clean environment:

```
sudo apt-get remove node-less
```

After issuing these two commands, ensure that the following files do not exist, and if they exist delete them:

```
/usr/bin/lessc
/usr/local/bin/lessc
```

Also check the following directories (and remove them if they exist):

```
/node_modules/less
/usr/bin/node_modules/less
/usr/node_modules/less
/usr/local/bin/node_modules/less
/usr/local/node_modules/less
~/.node_modules/less
~/.node_libraries/less
```

All that files and directories may be generated in various ways. Different installation methods lead to different directories used. Removing all that files is important to ensure that *nothing* conflicts: you should always have one, and just one, version of a software installed on your system. The only exception is when the distribution itself provides different versions of the same software (in this case, package are made so that they don't conflict with each other).

Now you have a clean environment and can install **node-less**:

```
sudo apt-get install node-less
```

Note that the **node-less** package does not ship `/usr/bin/recess`, just `/usr/bin/lessc`, so it's perfectly OK if `recess --compile` fails (or, better, it **must** fail).

If `lessc` still does not work, please check the output of `which lessc`. Remember: if it does return something different than `/usr/bin/lessc`, it means that you are not using lessc from the distribution package, but something else.

Comment: You don't need to prefer distro packages, but mixing distro and compiled packages that provide similar binaries is really a recipe for problems.

Comment: @Javier: hi. Surely you don't need to choose only distribution packages, but we are on Ask Ubuntu and I think the most appropriate solution is one that tells you how to use the distribution packages. :-)

Comment: Just a brilliant answer, thanks for the careful explanation.  Everything is working now as it should.  Not sure how I managed to get a dud version of the npm less installed, but I caution on not mixing similar distro & compiled packages is well noted.  It is a pity that it's often not possible to rely only on distro packages though, particularly in with ruby, etc.

Comment: @cboettig: thanks for your feedback, it's really appreciated. As Javier pointed out, you are not forced to use distribution packages. But when you install third-party software, remember to not install it system wide. For example, I use Python Virtualenv, chroots, Linux Containers (LXC) and Qemu virtual machines when I need to run software not provided by the distribution (or when I need special system configurations). All these technologies (and many others) help you isolate the software, avoiding the pain.

Comment: Running `lessc` gives `/usr/local/bin/lessc no such file or directory`, but running `which lessc` gives `/usr/bin/lessc`. How do I tell it to use the lessc from `which lessc`?

Comment: See the answer from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables if you get the error mentioned by Jacob :)

Answer (score 2):

After following the steps from Andrea's answer you may have to run `source ~/.bashrc` if you're getting `bash: /usr/local/bin/lessc: No such file or directory` when you run lessc and when `which lessc` shows `/usr/bin/lessc`.  This is to update your $PATH environment variable.

Comment: Also note the answer from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables in addition to this.